# How to access nested dictionary in python. how do i access total_cases

Tags: python, json, django, dictionary

how do i access the total_cases, death in python

```
{'data': {'2020-05-28': {'critical': 0,
                         'death_ratio': 0.0047984644913627635,
                         'deaths': 5,
                         'recovered': 187,
                         'recovery_ratio': 0.17946257197696738,
                         'tested': 162730,
                         'total_cases': 1042},
          '2020-05-29': {'critical': 1000,
                         'death_ratio': 0.0049504950495049506,
                         'deaths': 6,
                         'recovered': 206,
                         'recovery_ratio': 0.16996699669966997,
                         'tested': 0,
                         'total_cases': 1212}},
 'status': 200,
 'type': 'stack'}
```

Comment: last have two braces

Answer (score 3):

`dictionary_name` is the name of your variable.

```
dictionary_name["data"]["2020-05-29"]["total_cases"]

dictionary_name["data"]["2020-05-29"]["deaths"]
```

Comment: can top most date cant be selected automatically

Comment: What do you mean by 'top most date' ? To choose each date you have to use different key name.

Comment: there are thousands date updated daily. I want topmost date total_cases when a function runs

Comment: Not the most elegant solution but works:
dictionary["data"][max(key for key in dictioary["data"].keys())]["total_cases"]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution.
[dictionary_name['data'][i]['total_cases'] for i in dictionary_name['data'].keys()]

Comment: It has error of 'a is not defined' while removing a the error occurs " 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
0bject has no attribute" 'keys'